# identify third party cookies

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies

Given a cookie with the common attributes (name, id, etc), is there anyway we can identify if the cookie is a third-party cookie? By that we mean a cookie that has been placed by website B while visiting website A. At the moment, I can see no ways of achieving that but perhaps I've missed something. I'm working on a project related to user privacy online and would like to get a list of websites that left third-party cookies in user's browser. I use Mozilla Firefox Browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way to tell when looking at the store of cookies. The issue is that a cookie is always first party with respect to *some* site; the third-party-ness relates to the *provenance* of the cookie. The only way to identify if a cookie was a third-party cookie is to examine the actual header which set the cookie and see if that cookie was set for a domain other than the originating one. Everything is made far more complex by the fact that a cookie can be set for a whole domain (thus `foo.bar.com` is allowed to set for `.bar.com` so that `grill.bar.com` will also see the cookie) and determining whether a suffix is a domain or not is *not* at all easy (e.g., some countries have multi-level domains).

The final problem is that it's easy enough for the site to request some resource from another domain for real, and set the cookie that way. That's formally not a third-party cookie, as it is being set by the domain it references, but it works in effectively the same way.

Comment: You explained it in a lot clearer fashion than I did. My current solution is to implement a 'cookie monitor' that will compare domain of a cookie to currently viewed webpage. Accepted your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Every cookie is set for a domain. You can compare domain names to identify 3rd party cookies. But maybe I did not fully grasp your question.

Comment: If you have a third-party cookie, say b.com, it usually is set by domain b.com. Even though it was placed while visiting a.com, i can see no data in the cookie itself that could have indicated that. There are some exceptions such as google-analytics where you have cookies like _utma and they're set for domain a.com and stillcan be accessed by google-analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Based merely on list of cookies created so far in the browser, there is no way to say if a cookie is a third-party cookie.